# Java - Email Signing

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, signing

I have some issues with signing emails in java.

I believe my code is good but when I receive the email in my inbox, it says that it is unable to verify the signature.

Here the code - Pretty straightforward :

```
  boolean isAlias = false;

        // Add BouncyCastle content handlers to command map
        MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();

        mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.superman.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_signature");
        mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.superman.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime");
        mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.superman.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature");
        mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.superman.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_mime");
        mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.superman.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");

        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcap);

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        InputStream ins = SigningEmail.class.getResourceAsStream("/keystore.jks");

        // Provide location of Java Keystore and password for access
        keyStore.load(ins,"changeit".toCharArray());

        // Find the first legit alias in the keystore and use it
        Enumeration<String> es = keyStore.aliases();
        String alias = "";
        while (es.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = es.nextElement();

            // Does alias refer to a private key? Assign true/false to isAlias & evaluate
            if (isAlias = keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isAlias) {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("***".toCharArray()));
            PrivateKey myPrivateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();

            // Load certificate chain
            Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

            // Create the SMIMESignedGenerator
            SMIMECapabilityVector capabilities = new SMIMECapabilityVector();
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_EDE3_CBC);
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.rC2_CBC, 128);
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.dES_CBC);
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES256_CBC);
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES128_CBC);
            capabilities.addCapability(SMIMECapability.aES192_CBC);

            //Cert info
            X500Name x500 = new X500Name(((X509Certificate) chain[0]).getIssuerDN().getName());
            IssuerAndSerialNumber serialNumber = new IssuerAndSerialNumber(x500 ,  ((X509Certificate) chain[0]).getSerialNumber()) ;

            ASN1EncodableVector signedAttrs = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            signedAttrs.add(new SMIMEEncryptionKeyPreferenceAttribute(serialNumber));
            signedAttrs.add(new SMIMECapabilitiesAttribute(capabilities));

            //Set X509
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
            certList.add(cert);
            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);


            //Signing generator
            SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                      new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()
                           .setProvider("BC")
                           .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new AttributeTable(signedAttrs))
                           .build("SHA1withRSA", myPrivateKey, cert));
            gen.addCertificates(certs);

            MimeMessage cloneOriginal = new MimeMessage(body);

            //Sign
            MimeMultipart mainPart = gen.generate(body , "BC");

            // Set the content of the signed message
            cloneOriginal.setContent(mainPart, mainPart.getContentType());  
            cloneOriginal.saveChanges();

            // Send the message
            sender.send(cloneOriginal);
```

Here what I get from mail :

I used the .pfx to generate the keystone with that command :

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /Users/sign.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /Users/keystore.jks -deststoretype jks

It signed from an authority and everything.

So the import and the code looks good to me I believe but it does not work, and I am wondering what I am missing.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, GoDaddy does not sell email signing certificate. You may want to read [this review by mozilla](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_an_SMIME_certificate) and [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/email-certificates-smime-certificates.html) to know how to obtain one. [This article](http://www.sslshopper.com/special-ssl-certificate-types.html) explain several types of certificate:

1. web server authentication certificate
2. Unified Communications (UC) certificate
3. wildcard certificate
4. Extended Validation certificate
5. low assurance/domain-validated certificate
6. code signing certificate
7. e-mail certificate
8. root signing certificate

Knowing which SSL certificate type can help you avoid many problems such as trying to use a certificate for something that it isn't meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the providers to get your code run but then it worked for me. Thanks!

```
MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();

mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_signature");
mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime");
mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature");
mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_mime");
mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");
mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");
```